# Power BI Kusto Direct Query generates malformed datetime KQL

Tags: powerbi, kql, microsoft-fabric

I have a Microsoft Fabric KQL database with an EventTime column of type DateTime containing timestamps, an example value "2021-04-20T08:03:20.3230723Z". I succesfully added the database as a direct query data source on Power BI, everything else seems to work but trying to create a slicer with EventTime fails with this:

[image].

I can see that the generated KQL sent to the database looks like this:

```
["ExpandDataForPowerBI"]
| project ["EventTime"]
| extend ["o0"]=["EventTime"]
| summarize  by ["EventTime"], ["o0"]
| extend ["t0_0"]=iff(isnotnull(["o0"]), todatetime(["o0"]), todatetime(datetime(1899-12-28 00.00.00.0000000))),["t1_0"]=iff(isnull(["o0"]), toreal(0), toreal(1))
| order by ["t0_0"] asc,["t1_0"] asc
| project ["EventTime"]
| limit 101
| project-rename ["c1"] = ["EventTime"]
```

The issue is with the hour/minute/second separators being "." instead of ":" in e.g. `datetime(1899-12-28 00.00.00.0000000)`.

Is there any way to fix this or is this a bug in Power BI?

Example of visual working:

[image]

After adding slicer, it breaks:

[image]

**Update**

Creating the Power BI report online in the browser does work. So it might be related to my region (Finnish)

Comment: Looks like a bug.  Can you share the visual and the DAX query that generates this KQL?

Comment: I'm very new to Power BI so sorry for not being able to give clear answers.

I create a brand new report, add a KQL Direct Query data source which points to a function which returns a datatable. 

The transform data panel is just this:
```= #"6fa69793-1e5c-4603-95a3-e85ea1e908c2"{[Name="ExpandDataForPowerBI"]}[Data]```

I can do visualizations which don't involve the EventTime column. As soon as I add a slicer with the EventType as the field, it will break the visual.

Comment: What's the other visual?  Can you add a screenshot of it working without the slicer?

Comment: Added screenshots showing the visual working and breaking with the slicer added.

Comment: And "Measure" is just COUNTROWS()

Comment: Hmm.  I can't get that to fail.  Can you possibly repro that with one of the KQL database samples?  Or an implementation of the function that you can add to  your question.  And/or open a ticket at https://support.fabric.microsoft.com

Comment: I managed to repro it in the sample database SampleIoTData table TransformedSensorsData 

Steps:
- Add that table as direct query KQL source
- Add slicer one, add field "PublisherId" to it, observe that it works (populates with data)
- Add slicer two, add field "Timestamp" to it, observer that first slicer is now broken after refresh

Comment: Still works for me.  You are using the latest Power BI Desktop? And where are you seeing that KQL?  PBI sends SQL to Kusto. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1US67.png

Comment: Thats interesting, yes im using latest Power BI desktop Version: 2.120.963.0 64-bit (August 2023)

The KQL is from the database using ".show queries" command, here is an example

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2kjp.jpg

Comment: Mine shows queries like `["TransformedSensorsData"]
| where (["Timestamp"] == datetime(2022-04-13 01:07:41.0000000)) and (["PublisherId"] == "0dee3500-8695-40ca-bcdd-957aabdf9759")
| summarize ["a0"]=count() by ["SensorName"]
| limit 1000001`  Perhaps if you could share the PBIX pointing to the sample.  I can re-point it to my copy of the sample.

Comment: Issue fixed, I still think it's a bug. See answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was locale. When creating the report in desktop Power BI, my locale was "English (Finnish)". Changing it to English (United States)" Fixed the problem. I think this is a bug in desktop Power BI, and the KQL queries should work regardless of locale, given that KQL only supports one type of datetime format.

[image]

Comment: This happened to me as well month ago. I hated it.